# How to use jsonb - and #- to delete in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, jsonb

I have a jsonb column named "randomblocks" in my postgres database table "blocks" having data similar to the json:

```
{
"block": {
    "1": {
        "color": [
            "black",
            "white"
        ]
    },
    "2": {
        "color": [
            "grey",
            "silver"
        ]
    }
}
}
```

If I wanted to delete the "block" > "2", the query according to postgres [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) would be similar to:

```
UPDATE blocks SET randomblocks = randomblocks #- '{block,2}' where blockid=1;
```

At the moment I am stuck with raw query which is not an elegant way to achieve this:

```
stmt = text("UPDATE blocks SET randomblocks = randomblocks #- '{block, :x}' where blockid= :y")
stmt = stmt.bindparams(x=2, y=1)
db.session.execute(stmt)
```

How to write the same query using sqlalchemy without using the raw query and preferably the orm way if possible?

Comment: Include your model in the question, if asking an ORM question. Though it's possible to deduce from your query etc., why make everyone go through that?

Comment: @IljaEverilä I skipped the model for the sake of simplicity. Consider a block object of class Block with properties blockid and randomblocks and to update it like: block.randomblocks = block.randomblocks #- '{block,2}' before the commit

Comment: All in all, couldn't find a proper mapped operator method for that, so you could revert to using `Block.randomblocks.op('#-')(postgresql.array(['block','2']))` in a `Query.update()`.